# Key considered pressed for a while after released in Java using Lanterna

Tags: java, input, lanterna

I am doing a college project and need to use Java and Lanterna to develop a game.

I have the game almost completed but need to fix this problem, where if I press a key for too long, after releasing it the game still thinks that I am pressing it, stopping only after a while.

The key press is read using the `.pollInput()` Lanterna method, and only made once per frame. The game has a set frame rate.

I tried changing the frame rate in order to see if that affected anything, but it didn't seem to have a direct influence. Because I am only checking the input once per frame and this problem still occurs, I though that the only way this can happen is if the Lanterna saves in the Input pool, the key presses in a constant speed, not affected by the calling  of the `.pollInput` method.

Considering this, is there any way for me to fix this problem?

I am guessing that changing the frame rate did not affect anything since it's already too slow for the speed in which Lanterna adds inputs to the pool. I had a much simpler version of the game, and when the frame rate was high the problem did not occur.

I appreciate all the feedback, thanks for the support!

Comment: I would think the key being held down is repeating and filling up the operating system typeahead buffer. I've never heard of Lanterna, but `pollInput()` sounds like it would just read the keypresses, so if the key repeat rate is faster than the frame rate, the buffer is going to fill up and then not get 'drained' until sometime after the key is released, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Same here, never heard of Lanterna before. I second @DavidConrad's comment, a possible solution for it would be to use some sort of KeyRelease event, and cancel/ignore the remaining processing of whatever `pollInput()` is doing. Now be advised depending on how you code this it might generate some nasty hard to find side effects.